# Script for parsing winword doc document

Tags: ms-word

MS Office Word document has the following structure:

```
Title(line, font size 14)
Description(paragraph, font size 12)
Some other paragraphs of text(font size 12)
```

I need script to extract Titles and Descriptions from this document(and, for example, to put them into Excel table). ANy ideas about such script?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may need to clarify the question a little more. But as far as script goes,

1) Use VBA (It's part of Word), you could easily write a little VBA macro that would load up a doc, parse that info, write it to a CSV file and close the doc, then repeat for the next doc.
2) VBScript (basically same as above but use VBScript as the language, similiar but not exactly the same as VBA).
3) JavaScript (same idea as VBScript above).
4) Powershell (a .net way to do the same thing).

Personally, if this is a one off deal, I'd go with VBA and be done with it.